# Category tree in a laravel routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am doing a product catalogue with Eloquent and i have 2 models: product and category. Each category can have many products and each product belongs to one category. My category model has the following columns:

```
id
title
parent_id
slug
```

and product model has:

```
id
title
body
category_id
slug
```

When i am creating a category, by default parent_id set to 0, which means it's not a subcategory, but parent, i.e.:

```
Cars
--Audi
```

Cars has parent_id set to 0 and Audi has parent_id set to 1 (because Cars category's id is 1). Then i created model for nested rows:

ItemsHelper.php:

```
<?php

  class ItemsHelper {

    private $items;

    public function __construct($items) {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function htmlList() {
        return $this->htmlFromArray($this->itemArray());
    }

    private function itemArray() {
        $result = array();
        foreach($this->items as $item) {
            if ($item->parent_id == 0) {
                $result[$item->title] = $this->itemWithChildren($item);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function childrenOf($item) {
        $result = array();
        foreach($this->items as $i) {
            if ($i->parent_id == $item->id) {
              $result[] = $i;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function itemWithChildren($item) {
        $result = array();
        $children = $this->childrenOf($item);
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $result[$child->title] = $this->itemWithChildren($child);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function htmlFromArray($array) {
        $html = '';
        foreach($array as $k => $v) {
            $html .= "<ul>";
            $html .= "<li>" . $k . "</li>";
            if(count($v) > 0) {
                $html .= $this->htmlFromArray($v);
            }
            $html .= "</ul>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
  }
```

then i am printing category hierarchy in a blade file:

```
{{ $itemsHelper->htmlList() }}
```

it outputs a category tree. I can access cars category by visiting `/category/cars` but if it's children of cars category then it should be `/category/cars/audi` How can i set that in my routes?

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
```

Comment: You need to add another route manually, pointing either at a method in your `CategoryController`, or another controller or closure. A standard resource controller does not create any routes that would handle a `/category/cars/audi` syntax.

Comment: I'd recommend using `NULL` instead of `0` to indicate lack of `parent`.

Comment: if i manually create /category/{cat1}/{cat2} it would be max 2 levels deeper and i can have 10 levels, ie: /category/cars/audi/a8